# Count occurrences of each letter in a file?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, file, optimization

How to find the occurrence of letters A-Z regardless(ignore case) in a optimized way even if the file size is as large as 4GB or more ? What could be the different implementations possible in C++/C ?

One implementation is  :

Pseudocode

```
A[26]={0}
loop through each character ch in file
If isalpha(ch)
     A[tolower(ch)-'A']+ = 1
End If
end loop
```

Comment: If you are operating on 4GB files, then the running time of this program is going to be dominated by disk I/O. Optimizing the counting will be pointless. You need to optimize the I/O part.

Comment: Depending on your application and the stuff around, it might be an option to cache already computed statistics on the disc / in a database with their modification time. Just giving an idea...

Comment: sorry man. but for such a problem you have to think of using apache hadoop and map reduce. BTW, the first basic problem they introduce is a duplicate to yours.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Still can we not use the parallel hardware in our system to optimize our code someway ? Is this is possibility ?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Can you send the link to the duplicate ??

Comment: @SRINI794, you don't usually have parallel hardware paths to your disk.

Comment: Hi, here's your [link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount) but this is apache hadoop counting words, with simple modifications you can run it to find counting letters. Just to know.

Comment: @MarkRansom No I mean dividing the data first and then loading these small chunks in terms of  2,3 or 4 chunks at a time and execute parallely on given multicore CPU/GPU ?

Comment: welcome, hope it helped :)

Comment: @SRINI794, that was the point Raymond Chen was trying to make - you could speed up the counting by 1000 times and it wouldn't make a difference, you're still waiting for the disk. More threads would actually hurt you since they would probably be reading from different parts of the disk.

Answer (score 9):

Not much optimization left, I think.

- Instead of computing `tolower()-'A'` for each element, just count occurrences of each character (in a `char[256]` accumulator), and do the case-aware computation afterwards (Might be more efficient or not, just try).
- Be sure to use buffered input (`fopen`, perhaps assign larger buffer with [`setvbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf)).

Eg:

```
acum[256]={0}
loop through each character 'c' in file
     acum[c]++
end loop
group counts corresponding to same lowercase/uppercase letters
```

Also, bear in mind that this assumes ASCII or derived (one octet = one character) encoding.

Comment: Gotta be careful with the array of 256, since half the character values will be negative. `A[c+128]++`

Comment: @MarkRansom: Not if using `getc` and `ch` is an int.

Comment: @leonbloy, interesting question. I've always used `fread` or `read` to get a bunch at a time, so I don't know the behavior of `getc` all that well.

Comment: Perhaps memory mapping the file may have some benefit, but otherwise this is about as good as it gets without chunking the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be instantaneous with 4GB. I see know way to do what you are doing much faster.

In addition, your code wouldn't handle tabs, spaces or other characters. You need to use `isalpha()` and only increment the count if it returns true.

Note that `isalpha()` is extremely fast. But, again, this code would not be instantaneous with a very large input.

```
TCHAR a[26] = { 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (isalpha(text[i]))
    {
        a[tolower(text[i]) - 'a']++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know my implementation is very slow !! I just wanted to know if there is a faster way to implement this ?

Comment: And I thought I answered that, in addition to showing something your code was missing.